# Do I need to include an image in every single blog post?

Tags: seo, images

I have read a lot about including an image that has some visual representation of the content of the post and that's what I recommend to my clients. However, one of my client does not want to use images in any of her posts as the blog is about simplicity and use of a photo will limit a visitor's imagination.

Is it a healthy practice (from Search Engines' point of view) to not include any image in the content?

Comment: It really doesn't matter from an seo perspective. But from what i've read users seem to like it. That may help you get links.

Comment: I can see that side @JohnConde but this particular blog has a different set of audience. Maybe, I can suggest the use of some of her quotes as featured image?

Comment: That would work just as well I suspect

Comment: There are two reasons why people recommend an image; one - visual stimulation encourages engagement and reading further, and two - it is another opportunity to use keywords. Understanding your customers point of view, and it is completely understandable, the suggestion to use a quote in an image is a good compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the benefit of ranking for search queries in image search engines by including imagery in your blog posts. This in itself can prove a substantial traffic driver.

The general consensus is though, that visuals in web content have a much higher engagement rate and aids the effect of any copy as it's just one way of breaking up the text into easily readable sections.

It is recommended to include imagery, especially for more lengthier pieces of content but it's not necessarily vital and isn't to say you can't rank well in organic search without images.

Social Media Today [previously published](http://socialmediatoday.com/mike-allton/1209636/10-benefits-using-images-blogs) a piece on some of the potential benefits of using images in blog posts. Whilst this piece only touches the surface really and is relatively basic, it gives some insight as to what benefits there can be from utilising visuals in blog content.